# Ability to set character limit in BuddyPress?

Tags: buddypress, limit

I would like to limit characters in BuddyPress posts to certain limit . Ex: Set it to the limit of 150 ... just like twitter's 140.

Googled about it and found nothing. Does any one have Idea on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution is to add a maxlength attribute to the textarea field. For example

```
<textarea maxlength="140">

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Try With the following plugin.,

http://bavotasan.com/2009/excerpt-and-content-word-limit-wordpress-plugin/

Also try with this too.,

http://buddypress.org/community/groups/creating-extending/forum/topic/character-limit-and-counter-for-the-new-status-updates-component/

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered 3 years ago on wordpress.org. 
[Here is the function](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-limit-characters-in-content), which you can easily modify to your needs.

Comment: Hi ommunist, welcome to WPSE. Can you provide the code in your answer? Answers with just a link are considered poor quality, and become useless should the link ever die. Thanks!